# c# console check is this space or x? not a string in a setcursorposition

Tags: c#, null, console

I am doing a homework whick looks like xox tic tac toe game and I have a big problem. When I put X in a location that is already filled, the game should give an error or something. I cant check if it's null or full. What should I do?

I am putting X with set cursor position command but I cant check them because they are not a string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp18
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int xcor,ycor,counter;
        bool win=false,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
        counter = 0;

        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 2);
        Console.Write("-------- Turn " + counter + " --------");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(3, 6);
        Console.Write("  1  2  3 ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 7);
        Console.Write(" + -  -  - +");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 8);
        Console.Write("1|         |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 9);
        Console.Write("2|         |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 10);
        Console.Write("3|         |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 11);
        Console.Write(" + -  -  - +");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 3);
        Console.Write("generated piece");

        do
        {
            /*üretim*/
            generatepieces:
            counter++;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 2);
            Console.Write("-------- Turn " + counter + " --------");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 5);
            Console.Write("               ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 6);
            Console.Write("               ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 7);
            Console.Write("               ");

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int x = rnd.Next(1,6);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 5);
            if (x == 1)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 5);
                Console.WriteLine(" x ");
            }
            else if (x == 2)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 5);
                Console.WriteLine(" x x ");
            }
            else if (x == 3)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 5);
                Console.WriteLine(" x x x ");
            }
            else if (x == 4)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 5);
                Console.WriteLine(" x ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 6);
                Console.WriteLine(" x ");
            }
            else if (x == 5)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 5);
                Console.WriteLine(" x ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 6);
                Console.WriteLine(" x ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 7);
                Console.WriteLine(" x ");
            }

            /*isteme*/

            bastangir:
            Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 12);
            Console.Write(new String(' ', Console.BufferWidth - 1));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 13);
            Console.Write(new String(' ', Console.BufferWidth - 1));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 12);
            Console.Write("x coordinate = ");
            xcor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 15);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.BufferWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 13);
            Console.Write("y coordinate = ");
            ycor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            /*yazma*/

            if (xcor > 3 || ycor > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Hatalı girdi");
                goto bastangir;
            }
            if (xcor == 0 && ycor == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Pas geçti");
                goto generatepieces;
            }

            else if (x == 2 && xcor == 3)

            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hatalı Girdi");
                goto bastangir;
            }
            else if (x == 3 && xcor != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hatalı Girdi");
                goto bastangir;
            }

            else if (x == 4 && ycor == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hatalı Girdi");
                goto bastangir;
            }

            else if (x == 5 && ycor != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hatalı Girdi");
                goto bastangir;
            }

            else if (x == 1)

            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 7 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x ");
            }

            else if (x == 2)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 7 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x  x ");
            }

            else if (x == 3)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 7 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x  x  x ");
            }
            else if (x == 4)

            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 7 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 8 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x ");

            }
            else if (x == 5)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 7 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 8 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + 3 * xcor, 9 + ycor);
                Console.Write(" x ");
            }
        } while (win==false);

    Console.Read();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: The general rule for games is: You got a gamestate in teh code. Then you deal with priting that gamestate to the User. What you are doing is overwriting the already written parts of the Screen. This is a dead end of development. Sorry, but I can not think of any way to programm yourself out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this code a a little bit ... overhead :)

For tic tac toe, you can use for example matrix ... lets say

```
int[][] field = new int[3][3];
```

0) Lets say that x is 1 and o is 0 and default value is -1
1) assign default values to -1
2) print table to user
3) ask user where does he want to put x (you need x and y coordinate)
4) field[xcord-1][ycord-1] = 1 if this field has default value
5) print table to user
6) check if user has won the game (with loop!)

and repeat statements ... and yeah...things like print table to user ... use function ;)

Have fun